# How to decouple web service from the html response controllers?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC to build a web application for which a longer term goal is to build it as a web service that shall be consumed by multiple clients(web, android, iphone etc), but to build a quick prototype I am looking to build the web application that would serve as the html response(due to lack of expertise in front end MVC frameworks). The plan is that later the web application would be turned into single page app served by the web service apis.

My concern is which of the two approaches should I go with:

1. Build a webservice first by exposing controllers through one application serving JSON based API's and another web app(separate deployment) that would actually interact with the web service. This makes our web service ready to be used by other clients.
2. The second approach could be instead of exposing our api through the Controllers, we can have another layer below controllers that would make all the ground for the apis, and then we expose one set of controllers for serving the web using server side template processing.
   Later we can expose another set of Controllers that would consume the ground API and convert it into a web service API. These Controllers could be mapped to separate urls, or may be the same urls can be used by putting some parameter for the response content type or setting the accept headers.

Please let me know which of the two approaches is better? The advantage with first is once we build the web service, it would be ready to be consumed by other clients at once.
On the other hand, the second approach let's us optimise on the bandwidth and overhead of deploying two different applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of having controllers call controllers (I believe this is what you mean in #2).  I also like the idea of separation of code duties.  If you want your WS API to truly be separate from your client, then your code should be separate too.  I also think this is a better design as it

1. Lets you focus on WS things in the WS code and UI things in the UI code.
2. Makes the code base of both easier to maintain since there will be (arguably) less code in each since they would contain only the parts needed there.
3. Allows you to make decisions specific to the WS-side based on what's best for the WS application and for the UI-side based on what's best for the UI application and not have to compromise because they are joined at the hip.

Some might argue that you are probably adding a lot of complexity, though.  But, I would argue that separation of duties is always a good thing and makes for a much cleaner, better solution.

Comment: I don't mean calling controllers from controllers, but writing separate set of controllers for UI and data, while the common ground work(business logic) can be executed in a layer below controllers(say a service layer). Also, although I know it's a good idea to keep the two code bases separate, it results in higher latency and more code because every time you have to make a http request from your ui app to web service app.

Comment: I don't know if you can make an argument for higher latency, but you could definitely make an argument for higher memory footprint as two separate deployments means shared code gets loaded twice.  However, one could argue that in a good MVC design, the 'V' part should be rather isolated anyhow. Also consider the UI code is most likely written in a completely different language usually than the rest, it all comes down to how you intend to deploy things and where you think your bottlenecks are going to be.